# Android: update UI from thread

Tags: android

To update a seekbar, I am using the following code:
My problem is that anytime the seekBar.setProgress() is call, other element on the UI become freezed, so I would like to have a different thread that update the seekBar in the main thread.

How to proceed ?

```
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        try {
            int pos;
            switch (msg.what) {
            case SHOW_PROGRESS:
                pos = setProgress();
                if (!mDragging && mBoundService.isPlaying()) {
                    msg = obtainMessage(SHOW_PROGRESS);
                    sendMessageDelayed(msg, 100 - (pos % 1000));
                }
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
};

private int setProgress() {
    if (mBoundService == null || mDragging) {
        return 0;
    }
    int position = mBoundService.getCurrentPosition();
    int duration = mBoundService.getDuration();
    if (sliderSeekBar != null) {
        if (duration > 0) {
            // use long to avoid overflow
            long pos = 1000L * position / duration;
            sliderSeekBar.setProgress((int) pos);
        }
    }

    if (sliderTimerStop != null)
        sliderTimerStop.setText(stringForTime(duration));
    if (sliderTimerStart != null)
        sliderTimerStart.setText(stringForTime(position));

    return position;
}
```

Comment: http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-asynctask-example.html

Comment: Or just place it in Runnable, and post it. See Handler's post method.

Comment: I don't think that call seekBar.setProgress() only can freeze UI. And UI thread exist only one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Activities have a [`runOnUiThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method that allows separate threads to update UI components.  Your `setProgress` method would end up looking like:

```
private int setProgress() {

    if (mBoundService == null || mDragging) {
        return 0;
    }
    final int position = mBoundService.getCurrentPosition();
    final int duration = mBoundService.getDuration();

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run(){

            if (sliderSeekBar != null) {
                if (duration > 0) {
                    // use long to avoid overflow
                    long pos = 1000L * position / duration;

                    sliderSeekBar.setProgress((int) pos);
                }
            }

            if (sliderTimerStop != null)
                sliderTimerStop.setText(stringForTime(duration));
            if (sliderTimerStart != null)
                sliderTimerStart.setText(stringForTime(position));
        }
    });

    return position;
```

}