# Android: Update UI from a queue

Tags: android, networking, user-interface, queue

I'm building a [fan app for my local cinematheque](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329537/android-http-requests-in-asynctask-are-not-concurrent). The app retrieves the screening schedule, which is stored as a `List` of `Film` objects with basic data - name and screening time.

For each film, I make an asynchronous HTTP call for the film page in the cinematheque site, to retrieve the full data - description, year, length. The results are parsed, converted into a `FilmData` object, and inserted to a `BlockingQueue`.

I would like the UI thread to update the film descriptions whenever an HTTP call returns with data. I can't use `take()` or `poll()`, because they freeze the UI thread.

I thought of two strategies:

- Polling the `BlockingQueue` from an external thread, and updating the UI using [`runOnUiThread`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801804/android-update-ui-from-thread).
- Using [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to poll on the queue in a non-blocking fashion.

Updating UI when any network call finishes quite a common scenario in an Android app. What's the right way to do it?

Comment: Create an AsyncTask for each movie. Specifying the thread pool size will actually limit the number of concurrent requests

Comment: Each movie can appear more than once in the screening schedule, and I want to make a single call for each page, so I need a central mechanism.

Comment: The "right" solution would depend on your architectural goals. I'd get clear about them first. Then answer the next level questions: why the queue at all rather than updating right from the asynchronous requests? How to map one item to several pieces of view? What if a web request fails? BTW, spawning multiple async tasks can cause problems on some OS versions and is overall not recommended, and you may not need any. Polling on timer may make sense if you want to group updates into "frames". And so on. Anyway, goals and constraints first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Handler`. E.g. Once the HTTP call has completed and you've created the FilmData objects, post a handler message to the `Activity`. In the `handleMessage` method of the `Handler`, update the UI.

Comment: That's probably what I need. Thanks!